# Firebase Messaging Topic quota exceeded

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm reciving error "Topic quota exceeded" when trying to send a push.
I thought Firebase Cloud Messaging doesn't had limitations, what I' doing wrong?

Comment: I have two questions. Are you getting any response like this **429 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED** ? and Are you using server environment or a batch import ?

Answer (score 1):

As for as I know there is no limitations. you can reach 1000 at once. But If you are over that firebase will need some more time to send to everyone. Even If you use **own server** to send push notification it will be same

The frequency of new subscriptions is rate-limited per project. If you send too many subscription requests in a short period of time, FCM servers will respond with a "quota exceeded" response.

There is no limit for topics, but there is a time limit for processing those after crossing certain number. FCM limit the number of concurrent message fanouts per project to 1,000. After that, FCM may reject additional fanout requests or defer the fanout of the requests until some of the already in progress fanouts complete. I attached the related DOCS below, please go through that for more info.

[Same question on a forum](https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/solved-limit-to-send-push-notification-in-firebase-notification.76589/)

[Topic messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)

[Fanout Throttling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#fanout_throttling)

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit how many topics you can create in Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM).

The "Topic quota exceeded" message is related to one of the limitations.

- It maybe due to allowed maximum of 1000 topics / groups in the special Firebase queue, also known as [fanout queue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#fanout_throttling). Firebase cannot process more than that number.
- Also it is possible to subscribe to or unsubscribe from topics with the maximum speed of [3000 queries / second](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#topics_throttling).

Please add a retry logic for FCM API calls.